# How to Merge a column from 2 sharepoint lists and display it in a ASP.NET GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, gridview

I have got 2 Sharepoint lists. I need to pick some random columns from both the lists and display it in an ASP.NET GRIDVIEW. I've done this code using Linq. but i'm getting an error stating that argument null exception.  may i know the reason for such error .

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace SharePointProject3.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sQuery = string.Empty;
            string sWebUrl;
            SPListItemCollection objProductListItems = null;
            SPListItemCollection objOrderListItems = null;
            string sViewFields = string.Empty;

            sWebUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;

            sQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";
            sViewFields = string.Concat("<FieldRef Name='ProductId'/>",
                                               "<FieldRef name= 'ProductName' />",

                                                     "<FieldRef name= 'ProductDescription' />");
            objProductListItems = GetListItems(sWebUrl, "Products", sQuery, sViewFields);

            sViewFields = string.Concat("<FieldRef Name='OrderId'/>",
                                              "<FieldRef name= 'Quantity' />",
                                                "<FieldRef name= 'ProductName' />");

            objOrderListItems = GetListItems(sWebUrl, "Orders", sQuery, sViewFields);

            var Orders = (from itemProduct in objOrderListItems.Cast<SPListItem>()
                          join itemOrder in objOrderListItems.Cast<SPListItem>()
                          on Convert.ToString(itemProduct["ProductName"]) equals Convert.ToString(itemOrder["ProductName"])
                          select new
                          {
                              ProductName = Convert.ToString(itemProduct["ProductName"]),
                              ProductDescription = Convert.ToString(itemProduct["ProductDescription"]),
                              OrderQuantity = Convert.ToString(itemOrder["Quantity"]),
                          }).ToList();

            if(Orders != null)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = Orders;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }


        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

          public static SPListItemCollection GetListItems(string sWebUrl, string sListName, string sQuery, string sviewFields)
        {
            SPListItemCollection objListItemCollection = null;

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite objSite = new SPSite(sWebUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList objList = objWeb.Lists.TryGetList(sListName);
                        if (objList != null)
                        {
                            SPQuery objSPQuery = new SPQuery();
                            objSPQuery.Query = sQuery;
                            objSPQuery.ViewFields = sviewFields;
                            objListItemCollection = objList.GetItems(objSPQuery);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return objListItemCollection;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also i'll be using an visual webpart to add the gridview into the sharepoint page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq2SharePoint is not good idea. There are many issues with that. Including performance issues. Sometimes it generates strange errors and it's very hard to debug it. You use CAML in your code. CAML can do join as well. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/01/20/sharepoint-2010-caml-list-joins.aspx) how to do it. It's handled by SharePoint itself and you will get single resultset.